# Refer to a Class in a Style

Tags: css, focus

I have a custom button implemented as an anchor. The button has an image and text.

When the button has focus, I would like to style it differently. Specifically, I would like to draw a dotted rectangle around the image and text. I would also would like to additionally style it based on another class.

Here's the button code:

```
<a id="searchButton" class="button" href="#">
    <span class="icon-search"></span>
    Search
</a>
```

Here's the CSS code with my questions:

```
button:focus {
/*How do I make a rectangular dotted line around the button text and icon? /*
/* How do I refer to another class that has additional stylings? */
}
```

Comment: `outline: 1px dotted gray;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have "button" but it should be ".button" instead since your tag is not a button, but rather your class.

```
.button:focus {
  outline: #00FF00 dotted thick;
}
```

In regards to the question, "How do I refer to another class that has additional stylings?", I believe you would need a library like SASS, LESS or some other dynamic stylesheet language because that type of functionality is not currently supported by CSS natively.

Answer (score 0):

You refer to a class by prefixing it with a dot (`.`), like so:

```
.button { /* styles go here */ }
```

You can achieve the desired effect with `outline: 1px dotted gray;`

```
.button:focus {
     outline: 1px dotted gray;
}
```